# Castle Windsor Registration - AddAdditionalInterfaces() to implementation UsingFactoryMethod()

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

Given:

```
public class IFoo { }

public class IBar { }

public class FooImpl : IFoo { }
```

Why does this work:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFoo>()
             .ImplementedBy<FooImpl>()
             .Proxy.AddAdditionalInterfaces(typeof(IBar))
);
```

And this doesn't:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFoo>()
             .UsingFactoryMethod(kernal => new FooImpl())
             .Proxy.AddAdditionalInterfaces(typeof(IBar))
);
```

When after registration, we assert that:

```
container.Resolve<IFoo>().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IBar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just not supported (`FactoryMethodActivator` doesn't support proxying at all). There's no good reason for that I guess, so feel free to [request that feature.](http://issues.castleproject.org/issues/IOC)